# Why the energy distance function give me null result?

Tags: r

As mention here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/energy/energy.pdf

the `e.dist` returns Returns the E-distances (energy statistics) between clusters.
And as inputs it accepts **data matrix** of pooled sample or **Euclidean distances**.

I want to compute the e-distance between 100 observations of my data set.

Look what I did:

```
> disteuc<-dist(DATABASE,method = "euclidean")
> edist(disteuc,sizes=100)
dist(0)
```

Why I get null value ??

This is the first 100 rows of my data set:

```
> dput(DATABASE[1:100,])
structure(list(TYPE_PEAU = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), SENSIBILITE = c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L), IMPERFECTIONS = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), BRILLANCE = c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), GRAIN_PEAU = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), RIDES_VISAGE = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L), ALLERGIES = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MAINS = c(2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L), PEAU_CORPS = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L), INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), INTERET_VACANCES = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L), INTERET_COMPOSITION = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), AGE_INTERVAL = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), ATTENTE_BEAUTE_1 = c(1L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 6L), ATTENTE_BEAUTE_2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MILIEU_VIE = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), PROFIL_SELECTIONNE = c(1L, 32L, 21L, 23L, 34L, 31L, 
15L, 6L, 1L, 20L, 14L, 34L, 9L, 28L, 28L, 32L, 42L, 20L, 32L, 
14L, 20L, 32L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 13L, 32L, 7L, 34L, 14L, 21L, 19L, 
34L, 18L, 34L, 31L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 13L, 15L, 32L, 12L, 6L, 19L, 
35L, 4L, 36L, 34L, 6L, 31L, 32L, 25L, 4L, 18L, 9L, 23L, 13L, 
20L, 34L, 39L, 5L, 9L, 34L, 9L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 18L, 31L, 20L, 
3L, 27L, 36L, 1L, 5L, 15L, 18L, 35L, 6L, 31L, 31L, 4L, 34L, 23L, 
23L, 20L, 7L, 31L, 3L, 33L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 13L, 7L, 23L, 32L, 32L, 
32L), NOMBRE_ACHAT = c(14L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 10L, 14L, 4L, 
3L, 10L, 8L, 12L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 4L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 16L, 3L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 
5L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 
12L, 12L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 14L, 3L, 18L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 17L, 
6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 17L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 13L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 14L, 3L), NOMBRE_CADEAU = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("TYPE_PEAU", 
"SENSIBILITE", "IMPERFECTIONS", "BRILLANCE", "GRAIN_PEAU", "RIDES_VISAGE", 
"ALLERGIES", "MAINS", "PEAU_CORPS", "INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE", 
"INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO", "INTERET_VACANCES", "INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT", 
"INTERET_COMPOSITION", "AGE_INTERVAL", "ATTENTE_BEAUTE_1", "ATTENTE_BEAUTE_2", 
"MILIEU_VIE", "PROFIL_SELECTIONNE", "NOMBRE_ACHAT", "NOMBRE_CADEAU"
), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only specifying a cluster size, if you have 100 data and they are all in the same cluster there are no distances to other clusters.

```
> edist(disteuc,sizes=100)
dist(0)
> edist(disteuc,sizes=c(10, 90))
         1
2 42.51959
> edist(disteuc,sizes=c(10, 40, 50))
         1        2
2 44.32714         
3 39.80484 35.26888
```

Comment: Antonio Roldan Diaz , thank you for your clear response!